# OpenGL multi-architecture setup

Tags: c++, opengl, visual-studio-2015, glfw, glew

I've spent over 8 hours on this today.

Here's what I'm trying to do:

I want to create a project that uses GLFW, GLEW and nanogui to build an application.

I haven't started yet with nanogui, but I can already tell it's going to to be a blast.

Anyway, my primary goal is to setup four (Debug x86, Release x86, Debug x64, Release x64) environments with openGL and have them all work. This is what I've got:

```
Solution directory
   Project directory
   include
     GL
       eglew.h
       glew.h
       glxew.h
       wglew.h
     GLFW
       glfw3.h
       glfw3native.h
   lib
      Win32
        glew32.lib
        glew32s.lib
        glfw3.dll
        glfw3.lib
        glfw3dll.lib
      x64
        glew32.lib
        glew32s.lib
        glfw3.dll
        glfw3.lib
        glfw3dll.lib
```

The Win32 and x64 directories have x86 and x64 files respectively.

Moving on to configuration:

```
(All configurations, all platforms)
Project properties -> C/C++ -> Additional Include Directories -> $(SolutionDir)include

Project properties -> Linker -> Inputs -> Additional Dependencies ->
opengl32.lib
glew32s.lib
glfw3.lib

(All configurations, Win32)
Project properties -> Linker -> Additional Library Directories -> $(SolutionDir)lib\Win32

(All configurations, x64)
Project properties -> Linker -> Additional Library Directories -> $(SolutionDir)lib\x64
```

I have also copied glew32.dll to project folder (x86 version) and to all of the configuration outputs (x86 for x86 and x64 for x64). I expected for x86 version to work at least.

This is the only file in project:

```
#define GLEW_STATIC
#include <GL/glew.h>

#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    glfwInit();

    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 3);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 3);

    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);

    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_FORWARD_COMPAT, GL_TRUE);

    GLFWwindow *window = glfwCreateWindow(600, 800, "Name", nullptr, nullptr);

    int screenWidth, screenHeight;
    glfwGetFramebufferSize(window, &screenWidth, &screenHeight);

    if (window = nullptr) {
        glfwTerminate();
        return -1;
    }

    glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);

    glewExperimental = GL_TRUE;

    if (glewInit() != GLEW_OK) {
        return -2;
    }

    glViewport(0, 0, screenWidth, screenHeight);

    while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window)) {
        glfwPollEvents();

        glClearColor(0.2f, 0.3f, 0.4f, 1.0f);
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    }

    glfwTerminate();

    return 0;
}
```

Aaaaand it doesn't work. The program returns code -2, meaning glewInit() failed.

Even if all this worked, it's not really what I want. I don't want to have to package glew32.dll with my program. In the end, I want my program to be a single .exe file.

So, what did I do wrong here and how can I change it to make it work?
Better yet, how can I make it work so I don't have to provide glew32.dll with the .exe?

Comment: If you define `GLEW_STATIC` then you have to link agains `glew32s.lib`.

Comment: Setting it that way makes glewInit() fail. That is a step in the right direction, but it still doesn't work. Besides, I'd still need the dll to make it work, right? P.S. The guy above me is not crazy, I updated the question.

Comment: What does `glewGetErrorString` say?

Comment: `window = nullptr` looks also terribly wrong.

Comment: It's the oldest error in the book... -.- Well, now the thing works, but it's showing white screen instead of whichever that color is supposed to be. Also, how do I make it work without the dll?

Comment: x64 configs still have unresolved external symbols. Also, I get this warning on all configs: `1>LINK : warning LNK4098: defaultlib 'LIBCMT' conflicts with use of other libs; use /NODEFAULTLIB:library
1>LINK : warning LNK4098: defaultlib 'MSVCRT' conflicts with use of other libs; use /NODEFAULTLIB:library
1>glew32s.lib(glew.obj) : warning LNK4099: PDB 'vc120.pdb' was not found with 'glew32s.lib(glew.obj)' or at 'C:\Users\Karlovsky120\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\SolutionName\Debug\vc120.pdb'; linking object as if no debug info`

Comment: Never mind, I messed up dependencies... I fixed it only for the Win32 version, not the x64... It all works now, and with no dll involved! It's magic!